# ''Did have'' to ''have had''

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, tense

Let's say you run into a long time no see highschool girl classmate a minute ago. Who grew hot, and you say:

> When we were still in high school, she **didn't have** this exceptional body curves, and now she has it! Wew!

To:

> She **have not had** this body curves before, and now she has it! Wew!

I have constructed these 2 sentences if I have done the correct thing to say that they are **contextually the same**, aren't they now?

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence is idiomatic English.

**When we were in high school, she didn't have such an exceptional figure, but now she does.**

**She did not have such a figure before, but now she does**.

Of course if you are talking to the woman herself, she may be put off a bit by the first sentence's implication that you used to find her slightly less attractive than a dog's breakfast. The second sentence has the advantage of ambiguity: no one can tell whether you are implying improvement or decline in her physical attractiveness.